# Ajax POST always returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax POST to a servlet, process the parameters and then send a response. It always winds up giving me an error.

Form html :

```
 <form id="login" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username"> Username : </label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password"> Password : </label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="*******">
        </div>
        <button id="loginBtn" onclick="posaljiLogParametre()" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Uloguj se </button>
      </form>
```

Ajax post :

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "LogInServlet",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: $("#login").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $loginParagraf.css("display","block");
        alert("DA");
                    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

Servlet :

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    JSONObject jsonReply = new JSONObject();

    System.out.println(username);
    System.out.println(pass);
    response.setStatus(200);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    jsonReply.put("success",true);
    jsonReply.put("message", "Please work this time");


    System.out.println(jsonReply.toString());

    out.print(jsonReply);
```

The system prints work just fine, and the username and password are printed out in the console.

Comment: what is the error that is thrown?

Comment: the first alert just prints "error", its a blank string with the other two

Comment: can you chk the reponse you get back from server ?

Comment: I edited the original post a little bit.. alert(data.message) prints "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell I have recreated your setup using an index.jsp page which includes the form and ajax call, and a servlet with a doPost method that includes your code.  The code appears to work as expected. I get a successful response with the JSON message.

My first thought was changing dataType: 'text' to 'json', but it appears to work either way.

I had to wrap a try/catch (JSONException) around your jsonReply.put statements to appease the compiler.

One thing that might be causing trouble is that your form includes a submit button which will fire the onclick event and submit the form.  I changed it to type="button" so that only the onclick event would fire.

Comment: Yes, you got the setup right, and changing the button type works ! :D Thanks